# How to import module in different folder?

Tags: python

I have this folder structure:

```
A
|---- B1
       |---- C1
              |---- D
                    |---- x.py
|---- B2
       |---- C2
              |---- main.py
```

and I want to import x.py when running main.py. I added

```py
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
from B1.C1.D import x
```

to main.py.

But I received a `ModuleNotFoundError`

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Don't alter `sys.path` in your code. Set `PYTHONPATH` in your running environment, or move `x.py` to a proper place that Python can automatically find it.

Comment: You don't show or mention whether `B1`, `C1` or `D` are actual Python packages, or just plain directories.

Comment: oh, capital letter meaning folder name

Comment: No, I mean, what is your intention of the folder structure? Is `A` the base package? Or did you just put `x.py` and `main.py` in some folders, without thinking about a package (structure)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't run a script inside a package. Python files inside packages are intended to be imported, not to be run(*)

Instead, move the script into e.g. a scripts directory, then make sure the root directory of your package (`A` here) is on your `PYTHONPATH` or in a place that Python can find, and import `x` in the script like

```
from A.B1.C1.D import x
```

The file and directory layout would then be

```
BASE/scripts/main.py
BASE/A/B1/C1/D/x.py
```

and you run your script from `BASE`, with e.g. `python scripts/main.py`.

---

If you have another module elsewhere in the package, use a relative import. For example, if you have `A/B2/C2/y.py`, then import `x` as follows:

```
from ....B1.C1.D import x
```

Yes, that's a horribly amount of leading dots, but that's what you get for a deeply nested package structure.

Of course, in this case,

```
from A.B1.C1.D import x
```

also works in module `y`, not only in the script. But relative imports show how modules belong to the same package, and can potentially be handy in case you ever rename the package.

Scripts, on the other hand, are not part of the package. They may use the package, they may provide an executable wrapper around the package, but they should not be included in(side) the package.

---

*) disregard runnable modules here, because that's clearly not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is python2, you can add__ init__. py in D dir
__ init__. Py content is empty